# Treeline.io sanitize inputs

Tags: sails.js, treeline

I have just started investigating into treeline.io beta, so, I could not find any way in the existing machinepacks that would do the job(sanitizing user inputs). Wondering if i can do it in anyway, best if within treeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treeline automatically does type-checking on all incoming request parameters.  If you create a route `POST /foo` with parameter `age` and give it `123` as an example, it will automatically display an error message if you try to post to `/foo` with `age` set to `abc`, because it's not a number.

As far as more complex validation, you can certainly do it in Treeline--just add more machines to the beginning of your route.  The `if` machine works well for simple tasks; for example, to ensure that `age` is < 150, you can use `if` and set the left-hand value to the `age` parameter, the right-hand value to 150, and the comparison to "<".  For more custom validations you can create your own machine using the built-in editor and add `pass` and `fail` exits like the `if` machine has!

Answer (score 0):

The schema-inspector machinepack allow you to sanitize and validate the inputs in Treeline: [machinepack-schemainspector](http://node-machine.org/machinepack-schemainspector)

Here a screenshot how I'm using it in my Treeline project:

[image: Treeline schema-inspector example]

The content of the Sanitize element:

[image: Treeline schema-inspector sanitize part]

The content of the Validate element (using the Sanitize output):

[image: Treeline schema-inspector validate part]

For the next parts, I'm always using the Sanitize output (email trimmed and in lowercase for this example).